# dialog not returning true, and as consequence not triggering onClick, because of event occurred

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, dialog

this problem will drive me crazy and i am seeking a solution;

I made a hidden div in my asp.net page, and a JavaScript function to show it as a dialog when a asp.net button is clicked, this JavaScript function is triggered by onClintClick; everything was working fine.

I added some asp.net controls in that div, and here some problems occurred. once the controls is clicked, the whole page makes a postback and the div get hidden, that does not make an interactive session with the user.

in this point I found a solution, which is more useful and makes the dialogue re-usable. I added an iframe into the div and made it show an external page. in that way, the dialog (in this case the popup div) will not make a post back when user interacts with the page in iframe. so far so good.

Now, I need a way in which the internal page speaks to div (in this case, the div is the parent) to close it, either with return-value: true or false (have in mind the div is dialogue, and the returning value is either true or false). fortunately, I found a way to close the div, but the problem it looks end the "thread" of parent. so the div, which looks waiting true/false value, does not get either.

in picture 01.jpg: when [delete] is clicked, an onClientClick function is fired to show the round-corner div which contains an iFrame to show another page:

```js
function MyConfirm2(btn, lcWidth, lcHeight, lcTitle, DivID, frm) {
    result = false;
    myDialog = $(DivID);
    document.getElementById('iframepage').src = frm;

    myDialog.dialog({
        title: lcTitle,
        modal: true,
        // appendTo: 'form',
        classes: { "ui-dialog": "lcDialog" },
        width: lcWidth + 20,
        height: lcHeight - 20,
        open: function () {
            $("#myDialogOverlay").show();
        },
        close: function () {
            //debugger;
            $("#myDialogOverlay").hide();
            document.getElementById('iframepage').src = '';
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

now, the user should click either OK or Cancel from the inside page, which should speaks to outer div and inform it to close ..below is the triggered javaScript function to perform the closing:

```js
var receiveMessage = function (event) {
    if (event.data == "close-iframe") {
        myDialog.returnValue = true;
        myDialog.dialog("close");
        return;
    } else {
        myDialog.returnValue = false;
        result = false;
        myDialog.dialog("close");
    }
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

the problem here is that although the closing perform its task perfectly, and the return value is true, but it *cuts* the thread of parent page so it does not response as it should be ; the dialog is getting close; but closing does not trigger OnClick event that should be triggered after assigning 'true' and calling myDialog.dialog("close");

in debugging the code, i found out it return to *function (event)* and resume executing the code after line ***myDialog.dialog("close");*** as it has not relation to *close: function () {* in opening /closing code

sorry for writing a lot of details; but please give me a hand and advise how to overcome this issue.

[image]

I made a lot of debugging and tracing, i even tried to trigger the event ***hardcodedly *** by .click() ;
but this will trigger the onClientClick as well and i ended up with an infinite loop.

I am seeking a way to let the [ok]/[cancel] buttons in the inner page to tell the outer div to close and trigger the the onClick. or a way to trigger the onClick event without triggering onClientEvent.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to address your initial problem instead of addressing a fix for your workaround with iframes.

It sounds like your initial problem was that when you click the button, it makes a postback instead of executing your javascript function.

The reason this happens is because the button is in a form and the button has `type="submit"`

To prevent the postback and let the javascript execute the `onClick` handler, you need to set the button to `type="button"`

I would try to avoid using iframes just to show a modal popup.

Comment: I am using asp.net button control... Not the ordinary HTML control.. In the iframe, i need onClick event and onClientClick event

Comment: The asp.net button control still renders as a vanilla html button. You can configure it to be any type of button.

Comment: I need a lot more than buttons.. I need calendar, dropdownliat, checkboxes, etc that make postback and crash the dialog.. Iframe is a good solution

Comment: You can adopt ajax and web methods, or you can adopt an update panel. See my answer below that shows how to allow a jQuery.UI dialog to accept/enjoy/have/use post-backs, but NOT collapse. So, correct use of a update panel can solve this issue.

Comment: The second issue is HOW to get a true/false back to the button click for the dialog. The trick here is outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75520459/c-sharp-asp-net-getting-user-confirmation-from-ok-cancel-message/75525888#75525888

Comment: See my new edit, I show how to get/return a true/false from a jQuery.UI dialog to return true/false to the server side button click. Take all of the above, and you can even now build a re-useable dialog control, and one that you can use over and over for any kind of prompt, and upon user hitting confirm, the server side code behind will run.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so a few things.

I strong suggest you don't bother or use an iFrame for this.

(The reason of course is that you can't really have the iFrame "talk" to the page that you placed the iFrame into.).

So, the next issue of course is that any dialog (you are using a jQuery.UI dialog) that has a post-back will in general cause the dialog to collapse.

There are 2 general solutions available for these issues.

First, adopt web methods. This so called "ajax" of the buttons and code of course is often the rage today, since the goal here is to NOT have post-backs, and push/have/run as MUCH code as possible in the client-side browser. The reason for this great goal is of course without a post-back (a page round trip), then the resulting web application will respond VERY fast, and in fact respond as good as a desktop application. When you go SUPER far with this design concept, then you can even have a spreadsheet or word processor run inside of a browser.

So, a lot of the frameworks today are "trying" and "wanting" to move as much code as possible to the client side. And you can avoid post-backs by calling/using web methods.

However, there is a secret weapon you can adopt with web forms, and that secret weapon is of course adopting an update panel.

If you place the popup div for the jQuery.UI dialog inside of an update panel, then you find that the pop dialog can withstand and survive post-backs.

Thus, quite much near all of your issues are solved with this approach.

So, let's say I wanted a start date prompt, and an end date prompt. And let’s say I used the calendar control. Well, when you use a calendar control, when selecting a date, a post back occurs. However, we want a start date, and an end date, and we want this inside of our pop dialog.

So, we have this markup:

```
<div id="startend" runat="server" style="display: none">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hStart" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hEnd" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <div style="float: left">
            <h4>Select Start Date</h4>

            <asp:Calendar ID="dtStart" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px"
                BorderColor="Black"
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
                <DayHeaderStyle Height="40px" />
                <DayStyle BorderStyle="Solid"
                    BorderColor="Black"
                    BorderWidth="1"
                    HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    VerticalAlign="Top" Height="40px" />
                <OtherMonthDayStyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue" />
                <SelectorStyle CssClass="btn-info" />

                <TitleStyle Height="40px" />

                <TodayDayStyle BackColor="LightSkyBlue" />
                <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="Ivory" Height="30px" />
            </asp:Calendar>
        </div>


        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px">
            <h4>Select End Date</h4>

            <asp:Calendar ID="dtEnd" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px"
                BorderColor="Black"
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
                <DayHeaderStyle Height="40px" />
                <DayStyle BorderStyle="Solid"
                    BorderColor="Black"
                    BorderWidth="1"
                    HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    VerticalAlign="Top" Height="40px" />
                <OtherMonthDayStyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue" />
                <SelectorStyle CssClass="btn-info" />

                <TitleStyle Height="40px" />

                <TodayDayStyle BackColor="LightSkyBlue" />
                <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="Ivory" Height="30px" />
            </asp:Calendar>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </div>
```

So, just keep in mind the design pattern is this:

```
 start of your div to pop

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>

       -- everything in here - including the calendar control


      </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>   --- end of our div
```

So, the div we pop has the update panel "inside".

Right after above, we have our jQuery.UI dialog code.

```
<script>

    function popdate() {
        console.log("start")
        var myDialog = $("#startend");
        myDialog.dialog({
            title: "Select booking dates",
            modal: true,
            width: "720px",
            resizable: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            appendTo: "form",
            dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
            buttons: {
                ok: function () {
                    myDialog.dialog('close');
                    $('#txtStartDate').val($('#hStart').val())
                    $('#txtEndDate').val($('#hEnd').val())
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                myDialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

        myDialog.dialog('open');

    }

</script>
```

And the post-backs for the calendar (code behind) is this:

```
Protected Sub dtStart_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtStart.SelectionChanged

    hStart.Value = dtStart.SelectedDate

End Sub

Protected Sub dtEnd_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtEnd.SelectionChanged

    hEnd.Value = dtEnd.SelectedDate

End Sub
```

Keep in mind, since this is an update panel, THEN ONLY controls inside of the panel can be changed by code behind. So, we dropped in 2 hidden fields, and that will allow other code to get/grab/use/enjoy the 2 selected values. And on dialog close, I also have some JavaScript code to copy the 2 values from the selected dates to standard text boxes - this was just for demo purposes, but it gives you multiple ways and multiple options for using the selected dates with client-side code, or you can use server-side code and use the 2 hidden field values.

So, with above, the result is this popup dialog, and one that can have post-backs.

[image]

## Part 2 -- how to return true/false

Of course, the second part of this question is that we all when using asp.net webforms of course use the "very" useful trick of dropping a button onto a form, and having BOTH a client side click event, and then the server-side event.

If the client-side event returns true, then the server-side code will run. And if the client-side event returns false, then of course the server-side button code is to NOT run.

A typical use case would be say to confirm some delete or dangerous option.

However, where the above falls apart is that jQuery.UI dialogs and in fact NEAR ALL JavaScript LIBRARY CODE IS NON-BLOCKING!!!

That means that when you pop open (call/use) a jQuery.UI dialog, the code DOES NOT HALT, and DOES NOT WAIT!

All such code is non blocking by design, and that means you can't halt code to WAIT for the user’s choice in the dialog. This works with the browser's built in confirm, since that confirm dialog DOES halt and is not asynchronous code.

So, say we have this button to delete a record, and we "confirm" the delete by using both a client-side JavaScript routine to return true or false.

Hence say a gridview with a delete button.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%"
    DataKeyNames="ID" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="First Name"    />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"    />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Descripiton" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            ItemStyle-Width="140px"
            >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/trashcan1.png"
                    Width="48px"
                    Height="40px"
                    onclick="cmdDelete_Click"
                    OnClientClick="return mydelpop(this)"
                    />

                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdEdit" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/edit2.png"
                    Width="48px"
                    Height="40px"
                    onclick="cmdEdit_Click"
                    style="margin-left:15px"
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note close how the delete button has BOTH a client side click event, and a server side event.

So, the function mydelpop() can return true, or false.

This JavaScript code:

```
<script>

   function mydelpop(btn) {
       return confirm("Really delete this Hotel?")
   }
</script>
```

So, code behind to load the grid is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()
    GridView1.DataSource =
        MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

And our delete button code (an image button, but it can be button, link button or in this case image button).

```
Protected Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim btn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblhotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    MyRstPE(cmdSQL)
    LoadGrid()    ' re-load grid update display

End Sub
```

Running above, we have this:

[image]

Of course, the issue is that built in confirm dialog looks REALLY bad.

So, let's now use a jQuery.UI dialog.

However as above notes, jQuery.UI dialogs are "asynchronous" and the code DOES NOT wait. So, we have to trick out the code a bit, since when we launch the dialog the first time, it will run, display the dialog, AND THEN RETURN false (so the server side delete code does not run).

However, we then select a value from the dialog (yes to delete), and then we set a flag, and click the button again (we click the button again with Javascript code for the user), and function returns true, and the server-side code now runs.

Nice bonus points of the jQuery.UI dialog is we can position the delete dialog on the correct/current row click.

So, now our JavaScript looks like this:

```
<script>

    var mydelok = false
    function mydelpop(btn) {

        if (mydelok) {
            mypopok = false
            return true
        }
        myDialog = $("#mypoparea")
        myDialog.dialog({
            title: "Delete Hotel",
            modal: true,
            sizable: true,
            width: '380',
            closeText: "",
            position: { my: 'right top', at: 'left bottom', of: btn },
            dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
            buttons: {
                Delete: function () {
                    myDialog.dialog('close')
                    mydelok = true
                    btn.click()
                },
                cancel: function () {
                    myDialog.dialog('close')
                }
            }
        })
        return false
    }
</script>
```

Our pop div area is this:

```
            <div id="mypoparea" style="display:none">
                <h4>Delete this Hotel?</h4>
                <h4><i>(this can't be un-done)</i></h4>
            </div>
```

And now the result is this:

[image]

So, note how the jQuery dialog returns false the first time it runs (the code does not halt or wait - so we pop dialog, and return false, and server-side button click does not run). Now, if user hits cancel, then we close the dialog. If user hits ok (delete), then we set flag = true, and click the button again. This time our pop dialog code runs again but now returns true.

So, above shows a clever trick to avoid having to use a JavaScript "promise" and deal with asynchronous code (such as a jQuery.UI dialog).